# An example of lifting a group action to the universal cover.

Tags: algebraic-topology, group-actions, covering-spaces

Through a [previous question,](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1672763/is-the-quotient-x-g-homeomorphic-to-tildex-g) I understood how we can lift the action of a group $G$ on a topological space $X$ to an action of a covering group $G'$ of $G$ on the universal cover $\tilde{X}$ in such a way that $X/G\cong \tilde{X}/G'$.

Now I am trying to work out an explicit example and I am stuck -

Let $\mathbb Z_2$ act on $S^1$ by conjugation. That is $-1\cdot(x,y)=(x,-y)$. The universal cover of $S^1$ is $\mathbb R$ with covering map $p:\mathbb R\to S^1$ given by $r\mapsto e^{2\pi ir}$. But I can't figure out a right candidate for $G'$. Can someone help?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint:

Consider the group $G'$ which is the semi product of $\mathbb Z_2$ and $\mathbb Z$ with the product defined by $((-1)^i,n).((-1)^j,m)=((-1)^{ij},n+(-1)^im)$.

$G'$ acts on $\mathbb R$ by $(-1,n).x =-x+n$, you have $e^{2i\pi (-x+n)}=e^{-2i\pi x}$.

Comment: Is it good now?