# How to lift an action along a covering

Tags: algebraic-topology, definition, fiber-bundles

Took from Lawson-Michelsohn "Spin Geometry", pages 80-81.

> Let $E\to X$ be an oriented $n$-dimensional vector bundle over a manifold $X$, and let $P_{SO}E$ be the associated $SO(n)$-bundle. Assume $\geq 3$. Suppose given $\xi \colon Y\to P_{SO}E$ a $2$-sheeted cover which is non-trivial on the fibre of $X$ (I.e. On the fibre of $X$ the covering is the universal cover $Spin_n \to SO(n)$). We can see $Y$ as a fibre bundle over $X$ by post composing with the projection of $E$. **To make this a principal $Spin_n$-bundle we must lift the action of $SO(n)$ on $ P_{SO}E$ to a compatible action of $Spin_n$ on $Y$. By elementary covering theory this lifting exists.**

My question is: what's the meaning of lifting an action?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general if a topological group $G$ acts on a topological space $X$ then each $g\in G$ gives a homeomorphism $\theta_g:X\to X$ defined by $\theta_g(x)=g\cdot x$. Let $p:X'\to X$ be a covering map. We say that the action of $G$ lifts to $X'$ and is compatible with the action on $X$ if there exists a map $G\times X'\to X'$ such that the following diagram commutes.
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
    G\times X' @>>> X'\\
    @V id\times p V V @VV p V\\
    G\times X @>>> X
\end{CD}

However, one may not always get an action of $G$ on a covering space of $X$. It is reasonable to ask if there is an action of a covering group of $G$ on $X'$ that is compatible with the action of $G$ on $X$.

Now when $G$ is a Lie group and $X$ has a universal cover $p:\tilde X\to X$ then there is a covering group $\tilde G$ of $G$ (which is an extension of $G$ by $\pi_1(X)$) that acts on $\tilde X$.

More precisely, since $\tilde X$ is simply connected we can use the [generalized lifting lemma](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/145028/path-lifting-theorem) to show that there is a homeomorphism $\theta:\tilde X\to\tilde X$ such that the following commutes
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
    \tilde X @>\theta>> \tilde X\\
    @VpVV @VVpV\\
    X @>\theta_g>> X
\end{CD}
and any two such homeomorphisms of $\tilde X$ differ by a deck transformation. The set of all such lifts for all $\theta_g$ forms a group $\tilde G$ that acts on $\tilde X$.

For more details you can see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1667068/on-lifting-an-action-of-g-on-x-to-an-action-of-g-on-tildex) or the book Transformation groups by Bredon.

Comment: thanks for the answer! what is the reason why you claim that "However, one may not always get an action of $G$ on a covering space of $X$"?
My first impression is that we have to choose a base point for each lift, and so a lift of $\theta_g$ is determined by (clearly $g$ and) a base point (i.e. $\pi_X$). But actually, we could still get a $G$ action, just by choosing a specific lift for any $\theta_g$ right?

Comment: I can't think of an example at the moment but I think this action may not be continuous. And continuous actions are usually the only ones of interest.